# Time loop - store vector data in a file without overwriting

Tags: matlab, vector, save, iteration

In my MATLAB code I would like to save the iterated data of all vectors, in which one is recalculating in each time step-loop (depended by time). I am very confused trying to find the best way to do that. I tried to save in a mat file, but I am getting only the last value. Do I have to make a matrix? And save my vectors (1 row-100 columns) to each row? So, I will have to have the maximum time step of rows in this matrix? Is any other solution?

Comment: Some example code or what you have done so far would be useful.

Comment: You might be looking for [`save('myfile.mat', 'myvec', '-append');`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html), but as Marcin says, posting some code will make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: I tried to post sample of my code, but I cant. The -append solution is not working. My vectors are redefined every loop. I need possible to create a new matrix, in which its raws will be the values for every time step. I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Was my answer of any use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mat file cannot contain two variables with the same name. You need to give the variable you save in each iteration a new name, otherwise it simply overwrites the variable of the same name in the mat file.

The easiest way to do this is to use the dynamic fieldnames syntax of MATLAB structures to create a new field in a structure using the iteration index in the name. This field can then be saved directly to the mat file (without the parent structure), using the `save`'s `-struct` option.

```
for a = 1:100
   A = rand(10);                 % Compute output to be saved here
   s.(sprintf('iter%d', a)) = A; % Save it to a new variable in a structure
   save('myfile.mat', '-struct', 's', '-append'); % Append to your mat file
   clear s                       % Clear the structure
end
```